# Perform CRUD operations from a custom website with javasript using the Microsoft 365 Dataverse API

Tags: javascript, api, crud, powerapps, dataverse

I'm here for some help, I was reading the documentation about the dataverse API but I'm not sure how to implement it on the web, I've searched for guides but the only thing I've found are comments like "Yes, it's possible" or "Yes , queries can be made", please if you know any more detailed guide or tutorial on how to use the API I would be grateful.

Documentation: Web API Data operations Samples (Client-side JavaScript)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/webapi/web-api-samples-client-side-javascript

Comment: That link appears to be the root of the guides and examples. What else are you looking for?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.